# Extending Yapsy pluginInfo (.yapsy-plugin file)

Tags: python-2.7

I've converted my own plugin system with that of Yapsy, which is quite nice, I have some problem understanding how I can leverage the plugin configuration file (the .yapsy-plugin file) to include my own configuration items.

Currently the plugins have their own configuration next to Yapsy's, I'd like to move them entirely into Yapsy.

I know it has something to do with the yapsy.PluginInfo class. But I don't understand how to use it. Something like that:

```
[Core]
Name = bt
Module = bt
AttributeX = 1
AttributeY = 2

[Documentation]
Author = Sjoerd Venema
Version = 1.0
Description = Bluetooth
```

Small minimalistic example?